# Marker edge colors or just other markers of matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar (Python Package) to every point

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to use color markers of matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar (Python Package), or just other markers, to every point?

Example:

```
err = np.array([0.0, math.log(0.0423746910453,10), math.log(0.26659516937,10)])

plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=err,marker='^',markeredgecolor='gray')
```

I would like to have a color marker, or just other marker, to every point (error).

- Point 1: 0.0 -> markeredgecolor='red', or marker='^'
- Point 2: math.log(0.0423746910453,10) -> markeredgecolor='blue', or marker='X'
- Point 3: math.log(0.26659516937,10) -> markeredgecolor='green', or marker='o'

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, you could however call `errorbar` for each point separately with different options.

Comment: @sauerburger I just tested this, it worked, but the line connecting the points disappeared. Why?

Comment: @sauerburger

- plt.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=err1,marker='^')               

- plt.errorbar(x2,y2,yerr=err2,marker='o')            

- plt.errorbar(x3,y3,yerr=err3,marker='X')

Comment: To add the line, you can call `plot(x, y)` first, which plots only the line. After this, you can start plotting the markers.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Please post as a reply, and I will mark as a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there matplotlib supports this natively, however you can simply workaround this limitation:

First, draw the line connecting the points with `plt.plot(x, y)`. You can then draw each marker separately by calling `plt.errorbar` for each point with different options.